# LDAP log spam - TCP ERROR Bad Ber Tag or uncleanly closed connection - B1

Tags: load-balancing, ldap

I have a loadbalancer infront of my ldap servers. However, the healthchecks from the loadbalancer is spamming my dirsrv logs with following:

`{ "date": "[XXXXXXXXXXX] ", "utc_time": "XXXXXX", "event": "TCP_ERROR", "client_ip": "x.x.x.x", "server_ip": "x.x.x.x", "ldap_version": 3, "conn_id": xxxx, "msg": "Bad Ber Tag or uncleanly closed connection - B1" }`

Is it possible to ignore this somehow? Without blocking the connection, since we have healthchecks on the port.